# Generalizing the columns of a Flask Table

Tags: python, flask, flask-table

I define a specific Flask Table as follows

```
class MyTable(Table):

    def __init__(self, table_id, rows):
        self.table_id = table_id
        super().__init__(rows)
    
    Code = Col('Code', column_html_attrs = {'class': 'apply-filter'})
```

Now, if I try to generalize it by moving the `Code` attribute inside the `__init__`,

```
def __init__(self, table_id, rows, key):
    self.table_id = table_id
    self.__dict__[key] = Col(key, column_html_attrs = {'class': 'apply-filter'})
    super().__init__(rows)
```

something goes wrong and it is no longer shown.

I've also tried with `self.Code = ...` (that is not what I want because it is not generalized) but it also fails.

### Conceptual question

Even if I've found a working answer, I'm still not fully satisfied with it.
Why wasn't my original code good as well? Doesn't the constructor of the parent class see the fields (dynamically) created in the initialization of the derived class?

Answer (score 0):

Found the [relevant example](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table/blob/master/examples/subclassing3.py), by looking for `__init__` inside github source code of Flask Table.
In my case I can do

```
def __init__(self, table_id, rows, key):
    super().__init__(rows)
    self.table_id = table_id
    self.add_column(key, Col(key, column_html_attrs = {'class': 'apply-filter'}))
```

that becomes, more generally:

```
class MyTable(Table):
    def __init__(self, table_id, rows, keys):
        super().__init__(rows)
        self.table_id = table_id
        for k in keys:
            self.add_column(k, Col(k, column_html_attrs = {'class': 'apply-filter'}))
```

### Conceptual answer

> Doesn't the constructor of the parent class see the fields (dynamically) created in the initialization of the derived class?

No, because the parent class has a **metaclass** that wants to read the attributes from the `__new__` and the metaclass is executed at import time when those dynamic fields are not present.

### Tl;dr

For the sake of it, you can recover the metaclass as `table.TableMeta` by importing `table`

```
from flask_table import Table, Col, table
```

Then you could do

```
class MyTable(Table):
    def __init__(self, table_id, rows, keys, filters):
        dict = {}
        for k in keys:
            if k in filters:
                dict[k] = Col(k, column_html_attrs = {'class': 'apply-filter'})
            else: 
                dict[k] = Col(k)
        metadict = table.TableMeta.__new__(table.TableMeta, 'MyTable', (Table,), dict).__dict__
        self.__dict__.update(metadict)
        super().__init__(rows)
        self.table_id = table_id
```

### executive summary

The above would work but it is only the **conceptual** answer in order to deeply understand what is going on.

In the real-world scenario, you simply have to carefully read the full README of the github repo. There is a paragraph [Dynamically Creating Tables](https://github.com/plumdog/flask_table#dynamically-creating-tables), just follow the instructions, there is a convenient `create_table` that can be followed by `add_column`, as you have finally discovered.